# Windows logo key on keyboard not working with shortcuts in windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard-shortcuts

So i'm studying for Windows 8.1 MCSA, and the book i'm reading list all these nifty little shortcuts for charms and what not. The problem is, none of the keyboard shortcuts seem to work, and I haven't changed anything related to the key mapping. I use Swedish layout for typing purposes, but that shouldn't affect the shortcuts like ⊞+i or ⊞+x etc.

Does anyone have a clue? I can't really keep studying if nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Does pressing the Windows Logo key by itself toggle between the desktop and the Modern interface? That's the normal behavior for that key.

Try plugging in a USB keyboard to see if the Windows Logo key works using a different keyboard. If so, then it's a hardware issue with your original key.

You can also test this using the virtual keyboard found in the Ease of Access Center Control Panel.

Comment: I used the virtual keyboard in Ease of Access Center, and that worked like a charm, so I tried to connect my real keyboard to another port (I do use a USB keyboard) but that didn't work. 
I will see if I can find another keyboard to test with. 
Thank you for the information though, I didn't know about the virtual keyboard.